# Performance expectation from BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have 3 tables inside bigQuery containing sample data, namely agents_data, orders_data & customers_data.

The total size of these 3 tables was around **1.8 GB** (6,300,000 rows).

[Take a look at the data](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/10O2FqXOOdshkToK9J3-Y39fQSNe1yl2h)

I have used below query to **join **these 3 tables and create a **materialized view** :

```sql
SELECT
    t2.food_item AS food_item,
    t2.amount AS amount,
    t1.address AS address,
    t3.agent_name AS agent_name ,
    t1.gender AS customer_gender,
    t1.customer_id AS customer_id,
    t1.customer_name AS customer_name,
    t1.date AS date,
    t3.phone_number AS phone_number,
    t1.zip_code AS zipCode,
    t3.rating AS rating
FROM
    project_id.my_dataset.customers_data AS t1
JOIN
project_id.my_dataset.orders_data AS t2 
ON
    t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
JOIN 
project_id.my_dataset.agents_data AS t3 
ON
    t2.order_id = t3.order_id
```

I am running the below query in BigQuery which takes around **20-23 seconds** and processes **814 MB** data:

```sql
SELECT
    t0.food_item,
    t0.amount,
    t0.address,
    t0.agent_name,
    t0.customer_gender,
    t0.customer_id,
    t0.customer_name,
    t0.date,
    t0.phone_number,
    t0.zipCode,
    t0.rating
FROM
    `project-Id.my_dataset.materialized_table` AS t0
GROUP BY
    t0.address,
    t0.agent_name,
    t0.amount,
    t0.customer_gender,
    t0.customer_id,
    t0.customer_name,
    t0.food_item,
    t0.phone_number,
    t0.date,
    t0.rating,
    t0.zipCode
ORDER BY
    t0.food_item DESC
LIMIT
  2000001
```

I have tried doing month wise date partitioning and clustering of materialized view on the ORDER BY field "food_item" but did not noticed any speed up.

So I was wondering that if it is the expected time for this particular query or we optimise it somehow ?

I was expecting to reduce the query time.

Comment: Did you have a look to the plan?

Comment: yes, I have checked the execution plan for the query, and there the sorting and output phase is taking most of time like 17-20 secs

Comment: Do you use a reservation? Did you perform several time the same query (with cache deactivated)?

Comment: No, I have not tried reservation yet. Using on-demand computing I found different processing times for the same query(cached deactivated) in the range of 15 sec - 25 sec. Can reservation help me speed up the query, bcoz I believe it's only for cost control.

Comment: With on-demand you are limited to 2000 slots. With Reservation, you can have more. According to the volume of data that you process, it could be more expensive or not, in your case, reservation will kill your budget, but you can go faster with more computing unit (slots) in parallel. Or remove the order by